# Why does potential appear to differ between classical and relativistic mechanics?

Tags: special-relativity, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

As far as we know the Einsteinian mechanics is the modification of Newtonian mechanics for very fast relativistic speeds.  But if Einstein's mechanics are used in low speeds, it'll give the same results as we get from Newtonian.

But suppose an electron moving in an extremely dim electric field and has gained a certain velocity of $10 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}} .$ Assuming electric field is uniform.  Now let us calculate the potential in both mechanics:

- **Newtonian mechanics:** We know$$
  \begin{align}
  qV
  &~=~ \left[\text{change in energy of electron}\right] \\
  &~=~ \left[\text{kinetic energy increased by the electric field}\right] \\
  &~=~ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 \,,
  \end{align}
  $$that concludes that potential is $2.8468 \times {10}^{-10} \, \mathrm{V} .$
- **Einstein's mechanics:**$$
  qV
  ~=~ \left[\text{final energy}\right] - \left[\text{rest mass energy}\right]
  ~=~ \left( \gamma - 1 \right) m c^2 \,,
  $$$V$ turns out to be $4.55 \times {10}^{-28} \, \mathrm{V} .$

**Question:**  What is the reason for this apparent contradiction?  Suppose this experiment is done in perfect inertial rest frame.

Comment: I deleted a comment that appeared to be answering the question. Please keep in mind that comments are meant for suggesting improvements or requesting clarifications on their parent post.

Comment: How did you get the V answer for the Einstein section? Your value is incorrect. I easily got $2.84\times 10^{-10}$ V.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question depends on a poorly done  calculation and is basically a "check my work" question.

Comment: @DavidZ The questioner says he can't see the "delete" option in the "share cite edit ... " list. I thought one could always delete their own question. What's up?

Comment: @BillN The gist of it is that the system doesn't let you delete a question with an upvoted answer. I believe this is explained in a post, or a few posts, on [meta], as well as somewhere on [meta.se], but I don't have time to look up specific links at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your calculations are wrong.  I did it on the

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html

To calculate the kinetic energy of electron for relativistic case (since its tidious to do it by hand with such small velocities). I find that $KE_{rel}=0.545 *10^{-28}J$ and $KE=0.455*10^{-28}J$

(I noticed that you wrote it it terms of volts, or calculated the voltage, but that doesnt change anything, The error should be much less then your suggestion)

Also you can find the derivation of  approximation.

Comment: I totally acknowledge my mistake.